# How to perform validation for Captcha using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to UI design. I have created Captcha, Please anyone give me an idea to validate Captcha using JavaScript.Thanks in advance. I have added my code below.

Code for getting new Captcha:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getCaptcha() {
    var chars = "0Aa1Bb2Cc3Dd4Ee5Ff6Gg7Hh8Ii9Jj0Kk1Ll2Mm3Nn4Oo5Pp6Qq7Rr8Ss9Tt0Uu1Vv2Ww3Xx4Yy5Zz";
    var string_length = 5;
    var captchastring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        captchastring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("randomfield").innerHTML = captchastring;
}
</script>
<style>
```

HTML Code:

```
</head>
<body onload="getCaptcha();">
<form name="randform">
<table style="border:1px solid #ecece4">
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Contact Us Form</strong></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter Captcha Code</td><td><input type="text" id="txtcode"/></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<div id="captcha">
<div id="captcha_gen">
<label align="center" id="randomfield"></label>
</div>
</div><input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="getCaptcha();"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Hm... so if your plan includes a string that is created on the client side and stored in the DOM, wouldn't it be very easy for someone (non human) to pass your test by reading the value from the DOM?

Comment: I am just trying simple validation using Java Script.

Comment: Store `captchastring` in the global scope, create another function that gets the users input and match it against `captchastring`. but as @reto said, using JS for captcha goes against the whole idea of captcha.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateCaptcha()
{

    var chr = document.getElementById("tbxCaptcha").value;
    var cap = document.getElementById("randomfield").innerHTML;
    if (chr==cap)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert ("Please enter valid verification code");
        return false;
    }
}
```